# STL algorithms and const_iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, find, constants

Today I wrote a small predicate to find matching symbols in a container.

But I'm faced to a problem: I want to use this predicate in a `std::find_if` call inside a const-method of a class, searching in a container that is a member of this class.

But I just noticed that neither `std::find` nor `std::find_if` are able to operate on `const_iterators` !

I checked on some C++ references and it seems there is no version of `std::find` or `std::find_if` that accept/return `const_iterators`. I just can't understand why, since from what I've seen, there is no way that these algorithms could modify the object referenced by the iterator.

Here is how is documented `std::find` in the SGI implementation:

> Returns the first iterator i in the
>   range [first, last) such that *i ==
>   value. Returns last if no such
>   iterator exists.

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting? Can you also post some sample code? Thanks

Comment: Actually, you just misread the documentation, see Pavel's answer below. If you test you'll see it definitely works.

Comment: Your question implies you've some code that doesn't work -  specifically "But I'm faced to a problem" - while actually you are simply thinking out loud. I downvoted this question becuse if you had tried it you would have seen it worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`std::find` and `std::find_if` can definitely operate on `*::const_iterator` for a given container. Are you by chance looking at the signatures of those functions, and misunderstanding them?

```
template <class InputIterator, class Type>
InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Type& val);
```

Note that `InputIterator` here is just a name of a template type parameter, and any `const_iterator` will satisfy the requirements for it.

Or, perhaps, you're confusing `const_iterator` (i.e. an iterator referencing a const value) with a `const` iterator (i.e. an iterator which is itself `const`)?

Comment: Ohw, guess its too late, I just walked over tens of documentation and each time I've read what i wanted, not what was written x(
Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 5):

`std::find` and `std::find_if` both take the iterator type as a template parameter, so they most certainly *can* operate on `const_iterators`. Just for a quick example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int main() { 
    std::vector<int> x;

    std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(x), 20, 2);
    x.push_back(3);

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator b = x.begin();
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator e = x.end();

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator p = std::find(b, e, 3);

    std::cout << *p << " found at position: " << std::distance(b, p) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This should be accepted by any properly functioning C++ compiler, and produce results like:

3 found at position: 20

Answer (score 2):

If by any chance you are here for the same reason as me:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘find(std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator, int)’
```

It doesn't have anything to do with `const_iterator`s. You probably just forgot to `#include <algorithm>` :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the same problem.  I had a member function that was calling `find_if` on a member vector, and the compiler gave me an error when I tried making the member function `const`.  It turned out that this was because I was assigning the return value of `find_if` to an `iterator` instead of `const_iterator`.  The caused the compiler to assume that the parameters of `find_if` must also be `iterator` instead of `const_iterator`, which it could not get from the `const` member vector.

Answer (score 0):

I just had an issue with this code:

```
std::string str;
std::string::const_iterator start = str.begin();
std::string::const_iterator match = std::find(start, str.end(), 'x');
```

The error was "no matching overload for std::find".

The fix I needed was to use cend().  It's confusing that cbegin() isn't required, I'm not sure why that conversion is okay (implicitly) and not for the end() as a function parameter.